# how to load a php file to just display the contents of the file, not executing it?

Tags: php

how to load a php file to just display the contents of the file, not executing it?

I want to see the contents on a web browser.  But I can't find a way to load without it executing the contents.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want nice colouring, try [highlight_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you're programming in php in order to view a PHP file, simply load the file into a string, then run it through [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) before displaying it. It will escape all the html special characters and cause it to be displayed literally.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [`fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [`fpassthru`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) should do the trick. Don't forget to send appropriate headers first. Alternatively [`readfile`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Answer (score 0):

If its just one large block, you could remove the  tags..

otherwise, just rename the file to whatever.php.txt and load it in a browser..